# Compiling C++ when two classes refer to one another

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I am trying to write a simple wrapper around a connection pointer that will return it to the pool when the wrapper is destroyed, but it wont compile because the ConnectionPool and AutoConn need each other to be declared.

I tried to use forward deceleration but it didn't work. How do I solve this? (using g++)

```
class Connection {};

class ConnectionPool
{
    Connection *m_c;
public: 
    AutoConn getConn()
    {
        return AutoConn(this, m_c); // by value
    }

    void releaseConnection(Connection *c)
    {
    }
};

class AutoConn
{
    ConnectionPool* m_pool;
    Connection *m_connection;
public:
    AutoConn(ConnectionPool* pool, Connection *c) : m_pool(pool), m_connection(c) {}
    ~AutoConn()
    {
        m_pool->releaseConnection(m_connection);
    }
};
```

Comment: design wise this is a BAD idea, you should try to remove the circular dependancy!

Comment: well, it's a localized issue and the benefit of not having to worry about releasing the connection (in face of possible exceptions) far outweigh the "badness" of this design problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233149/two-classes-and-inline-functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of forward declaration and separation of declaration from definition of members with circular dependencies works.  For example:

```
class Connection {};
class ConnectionPool ;

class AutoConn
{

    ConnectionPool* m_pool;
    Connection *m_connection;
public:
    AutoConn(ConnectionPool* pool, Connection *c) : m_pool(pool), m_connection(c) {}
    ~AutoConn() ;  // Not defined here because it accesses unknown members of class Connection
} ;

class ConnectionPool
{
    Connection *m_c;
public: 
    AutoConn getConn()
    {
        return AutoConn(this, m_c); // by value
    }

    void releaseConnection(Connection *c)
    {
    }
};

// Definition of destructor with class Connection member dependencies.
AutoConn::~AutoConn()
{
    m_pool->releaseConnection(m_connection);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use forward declaration:

```
class Connection {};

class ConnectionPool; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<forward declaration

class AutoConn {
//definitions
};

class ConnectionPool {
//definitions
};
```

Comment: I suggest you try to compile it. it does not compile.

Answer (score 3):

implement the functions after the point where the classes are defined

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for a forward declaration is:

```
class Connection; // no {}
```

If you write

```
class Connection {};
```

Then you are defining the class, and you can't define a class twice.

Also, shouldn't you be forward declaring `AutoConn`, not `Connection`?

Comment: this is not forward deceleration, it's just a deceleration so the sample compiled.

Comment: He did not define it twice; that is the *only* definition of Connection.  I am assuming it is just a place-holder to reduce the amount of posted code.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was your attempt at the forward declaration - my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration only tells the compiler "such a class exists". In your

```
AutoConn getConn()
```

since `AutoConn` is a value type, the whole structure of `AutoConn` must be known, so forward declaration of the class won't work. So you must put the actual declaration of `AutoConn` before `ConnectionPool`.

In your `AutoConn`, the type `ConnectionPool` is only referred by pointers. In this case the whole structure of `ConnectionPool` is not required, so forward declaration of `ConnectionPool` is enough.

Therefore you need to rearrangement the classes into this:

```
class Connection;
class ConnectionPool;
class AutoConn { ... };
class ConnectionPool { ... };
```

But notice that

```
AutoConn(ConnectionPool* pool, Connection *c) : m_pool(pool), m_connection(c) {}
~AutoConn()
{
    m_pool->releaseConnection(m_connection);
}
```

these methods require the compiler to know the members of `ConnectionPool`, so a complete structure is needed. To solve this problem the definition must be placed after `ConnectionPool`. Thus only the constructors and destructors should remain.

```
class AutoConn {
  ...
  AutoConn(ConnectionPool* pool, Connection *c);
  ~AutoConn();
}
class ConnectionPool { ... };
AutoConn::AutoConn(ConnectionPool* pool, Connection *c) : ... { ... }
AutoConn::~AutoConn() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to outsource the definition of all `ConnectionPool` and `AutoConn` methods, i.e.

```
class ConnectionPool;
class AutoConn {…};

class ConnectionPool {…};

AutoConn ConnectionPool::getConn() {
   …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include `ConnectionPool` header file in `AutoConn`. Just use a forward reference like `class ConnectionPool;` in the `AutoConn` header file.