# Why use #ifndef CLASS_H and #define CLASS_H in .h file but not in .cpp?

Tags: c++

I have always seen people write

class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

//blah blah blah

#endif
```

The question is, why don't they also do that for the .cpp file that contain definitions for class functions?

Let's say I have  `main.cpp`, and `main.cpp` includes `class.h`. The `class.h` file does not `include` anything, so how does `main.cpp` know what is in the `class.cpp`?

Comment: "import" is probably not the word you want to use here. Include.

Comment: In C++, there's no 1-to-1 correlation between files and classes. You can put as many classes into one file as you want (or even split one class across several files, although this is rarely ever helpful). Therefore the macro should be `FILE_H`, not `CLASS_H`.

Comment: See my [include guard advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744144/include-guards/1744302#1744302).

Answer (score 376, accepted):

First, to address your first inquiry:

When you see this in **.h** file:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

/* ... Declarations etc here ... */

#endif
```

This is a preprocessor technique of preventing a header file from being included multiple times, which can be problematic for various reasons.  During compilation of your project, each **.cpp** file (usually) is compiled.  In simple terms, this means the compiler will take your **.cpp** file, open any files `#included` by it, concatenate them all into one massive text file, and then perform syntax analysis and finally it will convert it to some intermediate code, optimize/perform other tasks, and finally generate the assembly output for the target architecture.  Because of this, if a file is `#included` multiple times under one **.cpp** file, the compiler will append its file contents twice, so if there are definitions within that file, you will get a compiler error telling you that you redefined a variable.  When the file is processed by the preprocessor step in the compilation process, the first time its contents are reached the first two lines will check if `FILE_H` has been defined for the preprocessor.  If not, it will define `FILE_H` and continue processing the code between it and the `#endif` directive.  The next time that file's contents are seen by the preprocessor, the check against `FILE_H` will be false, so it will immediately scan down to the `#endif` and continue after it.  This prevents redefinition errors.

And to address your second concern:

In C++ programming as a general practice we separate development into two file types.  One is with an extension of **.h** and we call this a "header file."  They usually provide a declaration of functions, classes, structs, global variables, typedefs, preprocessing macros and definitions, etc.  Basically, they just provide you with information about your code.  Then we have the **.cpp** extension which we call a "code file."  This will provide definitions for those functions, class members, any struct members that need definitions, global variables, etc.  So the **.h** file declares code, and the **.cpp** file implements that declaration.  For this reason, we generally during compilation compile each **.cpp** file into an object and then link those objects (because you almost never see one **.cpp** file include another **.cpp** file).

How these externals are resolved is a job for the linker.  When your compiler processes **main.cpp**, it gets declarations for the code in **class.cpp** by including **class.h**.  It only needs to know what these functions or variables look like (which is what a declaration gives you).  So it compiles your **main.cpp** file into some object file (call it **main.obj**).  Similarly, **class.cpp** is compiled into a **class.obj** file.  To produce the final executable, a linker is invoked to link those two object files together.  For any unresolved external variables or functions, the compiler will place a stub where the access happens.  The linker will then take this stub and look for the code or variable in another listed object file, and if it's found, it combines the code from the two object files into an output file and replaces the stub with the final location of the function or variable.  This way, your code in main.cpp can call functions and use variables in **class.cpp** IF AND ONLY IF THEY ARE DECLARED IN **class.h**.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I was trying to understand .h and .cpp for the past few days. This answer saved my time & interest to learn C++. Well written. Thanks Justin!

Comment: you really did explained great! Perhaps the answer would be quite good if it was with images

Comment: @justin-summerlin This line of yours "Because of this, if a file is #included multiple times under one .cpp file, the compiler will append its file contents twice, so if there are definitions within that file, you will get a compiler error telling you that you redefined a variable".  I tried removing ifndef and compiled my code. It ran successfully although it was imported in two files. I tried in linux with command "g++ first.cpp second.cpp". I agree with your other reasons except this. Its only to  prevents double declaration of any identifiers, but it'll not throw an error.

Comment: As clear as a crystal! Thank you for your explanation Justin.

Answer (score 16):

The `CLASS_H` is an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard); it's used to avoid the same header file being included multiple times (via different routes) within the same CPP file (or, more accurately, the same [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)), which would lead to multiple-definition errors.

Include guards aren't needed on CPP files because, by definition, the contents of the CPP file are only read once.

You seem to have interpreted the include guards as having the same function as `import` statements in other languages (such as Java); that's not the case, however. The `#include` itself is roughly equivalent to the `import` in other languages.

Comment: "within the same CPP file" should read "within the same translation unit".

Comment: @dreamlax: Good point -- that's what I was originally going to write, but then I figured that someone who doesn't understand include guards is only going to be confused by the term "translation unit". I'll edit the answer to add "translation unit" in parentheses -- that should be the best of both worlds.

Comment: I think "by definition, the contents of the CPP file are only read once" is stated a little strongly. You *can* `#include` *any* file containing legal C++ code. Stupid performance hacks to make programs get the benefits of whole program optimization even on compilers without support for link-time optimization do just that (the "main" source file `#include`s all the other source files first, effectively creating a single monolithic source file containing the entire program in a single translation unit). You *shouldn't* include the CPP files twice even then, but it's not "by definition".

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't - at least during the compilation phase.

The translation of a c++ program from source code to machine code is performed in three phases:

1. **Preprocessing** - The Preprocessor parses all source code for lines beginning with # and executes the directives. In your case, the contents of your file `class.h` is inserted in place of the line  `#include "class.h`. Since you might be includein your header file in several places, the `#ifndef` clauses avoid duplicate declaration-errors, since the preprocessor directive is undefined only the first time the header file is included.
2. **Compilation** - The Compiler does now translate all preprocessed source code files to binary object files.
3. **Linking** - The Linker links (hence the name) together the object files. A reference to your class or one of its methods (which should be declared in class.h and defined in class.cpp) is resolved to the respective offset in one of the object files. I write 'one of your object files' since your class does not *need* to be defined in a file named class.cpp, it might be in a library which is linked to your project.

In summary, the declarations can be shared through a header file, while the mapping of declarations to definitions is done by the linker.

Answer (score 5):

That's the distinction between declaration and definition.  Header files typically include just the declaration, and the source file contains the definition.

In order to use something you only need to know it's declaration not it's definition.  Only the linker needs to know the definition.

So this is why you will include a header file inside one or more source files but you won't include a source file inside another.

Also you mean `#include` and not import.

Comment: but how linker get to know that it's definitions are defined in that particular .cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

That's done for header files so that the contents only appear once in each preprocessed source file, even if it's included more than once (usually because it's included from other header files). The first time it's included, the symbol `CLASS_H` (known as an *include guard*) hasn't been defined yet, so all the contents of the file are included. Doing this defines the symbol, so if it's included again, the contents of the file (inside the `#ifndef`/`#endif` block) are skipped.

There's no need to do this for the source file itself since (normally) that's not included by any other files.

For your last question, `class.h` should contain the definition of the class, and declarations of all its members, associated functions, and whatever else, so that any file that includes it has enough information to use the class. The implementations of the functions can go in a separate source file; you only need the declarations to call them.

Answer (score 2):

**main.cpp** doesn't have to know what is in **class.cpp**. It just has to know the declarations of the functions/classes that it goes to use, and these declarations are in **class.h**.

The linker links between the places where the functions/classes declared in **class.h** are used and their implementations in **class.cpp**

Answer (score 1):

`.cpp` files are not included (using `#include`) into other files. Therefore they don't need include guarding. `Main.cpp` will know the names and signatures of the class that you have implemented in `class.cpp` only because you have specified all that in `class.h` - this is the purpose of a header file. (It is up to you to make sure that `class.h` accurately describes the code you implement in `class.cpp`.) The executable code in `class.cpp` will be made available to the executable code in `main.cpp` thanks to the efforts of the linker.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally expected that modules of code such as `.cpp` files are compiled once and linked to in multiple projects, to avoid unnecessary repetitive compilation of logic. For example, `g++ -o class.cpp` would produce `class.o` which you could then link from multiple projects to using `g++ main.cpp class.o`.

We could use `#include` as our linker, as you seem to be implying, but that would just be silly when we know how to link properly using our compiler with less keystrokes and less wasteful repetition of compilation, rather than our code with more keystrokes and more wasteful repetition of compilation...

The header files are still required to be included into each of the multiple projects, however, because this provides the interface for each module. Without these headers the compiler wouldn't know about any of the symbols introduced by the `.o` files.

It is important to realise that the header files are what introduce the definitions of symbols for those modules; once that is realised then it makes sense that multiple inclusions could cause redefinitions of symbols (which causes errors), so we use include guards to prevent such redefinitions.

Answer (score 0):

its because of Headerfiles define what the class contains (Members, data-structures) and cpp files implement it.

And of course, the main reason for this is that you could include one .h File multiple times in other .h files, but this would result in multiple definitions of a class, which is invalid.