# C - Headers including each other

Tags: c, gcc

I have a file `game.h` which has this declaration

```
typedef struct Enemy {
  ...
}Enemy;
```

And a function

```
void moveEnemy(Level* l, Enemy* enemy){
  ...
}
```

`Level` is declared on `levels.h`, so in `game.h` I have:

```
#include "levels.h"
```

Everything was perfect, until I had to use `Enemy` in `levels.h`.

So, in `levels.h` I added:

```
#include "game.h"
```

And now I get a compilation error:

```
game.h:34:2: error: unknown type name ‘Level’
  Level* level;
  ^
```

I have include guards on both .h

I don't know why I can't have on file including another.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't understand the question, is `moveEnemy()` defined in the header file? If it is, it should not!

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll put it in a .c to see if it works

Comment: No, see the answer. But YES never put functions in header files. Header files are meant ot include function prototypes, constants and declarations, definitions of structures or user defined data types, etc. Not function definitions, those belong to *.c* files.

Comment: Use 'extern'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246803/why-use-ifndef-class-h-and-define-class-h-in-h-file-but-not-in-cpp ?

Comment: Tried what? Include guards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a forward declaration, like this in *game.h* before the function,

```
typedef struct Level Level;
```

since it's just a pointer to `Level` this will do it.

Comment: it solved that problem, but created another. Now when I use the struct Level, as in "lev->map", I'm getting the error: derreferencing pointer to incomplete type. I was not getting this error before

Comment: Move the functions to the *.c* files, and then include *level.h* there.

Comment: one question. the includes should be on the .c, .h or both?

Comment: Maybe on both as per your setup.