# incomplete type error in singleton

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

I need a pointer to my main class from a singleton class. The singleton class header is included in the main class.

In MainClass.cpp

```
mSingletonInstance->mMainClass = this;
```

To avoid a recursive inclusion problem I do not include my main class header in the singleton class, I just simply use a forward declaration of the main class.

In Singleton.h:

```
class MainClass;

class Singleton {
    public:
       MainClass *mMainClass;
};
```

The problem comes when I try to access a method from the main class... I get an incomplete type error.

In Singleton.cpp

```
Singleton::myMethod(){
    mMainClass->someMethod(); // incomplete type error
}
```

The MainClass and Singleton are already defined when this happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you didn't include mainclass.h in singleton.cpp.

Comment: But you should do it. And after that find out what wrong with the other errors )))

Comment: Thanks, I used a forward declaration of Singleton class in MainClass.h, and then included Singleton.h in MainClass.cpp

Comment: redefinition of what? could you post a short version of your code somewhere? I'm sure that it is a matter of some typo or missing semicolon..

Comment: You'll need header guards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/c-header-guards