# C++ multiple inheritance and virtual class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to write a program with four classes: vehicle, car, airplane and flying car.

Flying car inherits from car and airplane, car and airplane both inherit from vehicle.

vehicle.h

```
class vehicle
{
public:
    vehicle();
    vehicle(char*, int, char*);
    virtual void setmodel(char*);
    //more functions..
    ~vehicle();
protected:
    char* model;
    int speed;
    char* color;
};
```

car.h

```
#include "vehicle.h"
class car:public virtual vehicle
{
public:
    car();
    car(char*, int, char*);
    void driving(std::ostream&);
};
```

airplane.h

```
#include "vehicle.h"
class airplane:public virtual vehicle
{
public:
    airplane();
    airplane(char*, int, char*);
    void flying(std::ostream&);
};
```

flyingCar.h

```
#include "car.h"
#include "airplane.h"
class flyingCar: public car, public airplane
{
public:
    flyingCar();
    flyingCar(char*, int, char*);
};
```

Also, the source files for every class include the related header files (so thart `vehicle.cpp` includes `vehicle.h`, `car.cpp` includes `car.h` and so on.. ).

The main function includes the `vehicles.h` header and `ifndef..`.

When I compile I get an error for redefinition of class vehicle in car.h, but since I already used the `virtual` I don't understand how I could solve the problem.

I suspect including the class headers in the class source files may be incorrect, since the inherited headers are already included in the inheriting headers themselves, but if I don't include them here the compiler will not refer to the class prototypes. As an attempt I enclosed everything in `ifndef..` with no positive result.

Comment: @CoryKramer Then the code would be subject to the diamond inheritance problem.  See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

Comment: @Daniel You are correct!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ that's much more precise, thanks. (still it is difficult to find that question if you're looking through the standard search),

Comment: @maja Well, it's easier to find, if you know [the actual problem are the include guards](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dredefinition%20error%20include%20guard) ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use include guards

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

class vehicle
{
public:
    vehicle();
    vehicle(char*, int, char*);
    virtual void setmodel(char*);
    //more functions..
    ~vehicle();
protected:
    char* model;
    int speed;
    char* color;
};

#endif
```

Because both `car.h` and `airplane.h` use `#include "vehicle.h"` so the `Vehicle` class will be defined twice when both of their respective headers are included in `flyingCar.h`.

In general you should have [header guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/c-header-guards) around all your headers, or [equivalent such as `#pragma once`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards), etc.

Comment: All right, so that's where they go (I had tried to place them in the source files..). I'm used to place them in the main source file, but I guess that's not a given (nor the most efficient way). Thanks.