# C++ - Type redefinition error & uses undefined class error

Tags: c++, class

This is my first time working with C++ and am really stuck with those two errors.

I have two classes and their header files, Deck.cpp, Card.cpp, Deck.h, Card.h

**First problem:** Am having a problem with using the Card class in the Deck class (that's what I understand from the error).

**Second problem:** Am getting a redefinition error for the Card class. I don't find myself defining the Card class twice so I'm not sure why am I getting this error.

**Deck.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       
#include <ctime>        
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

Deck::Deck()
{ 
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii - 1].setCard('S', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[10].setCard('S', 'J');
    deck[11].setCard('S', 'Q');
    deck[12].setCard('S', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 12].setCard('D', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[23].setCard('D', 'J');
    deck[24].setCard('D', 'Q');
    deck[25].setCard('D', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 25].setCard('C', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[36].setCard('C', 'J');
    deck[37].setCard('C', 'Q');
    deck[38].setCard('C', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 38].setCard('H', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[49].setCard('H', 'J');
    deck[50].setCard('H', 'Q');
    deck[51].setCard('H', 'K');
    startingIndex = 0;
    topCard = deck[startingIndex];
}

Card Deck::deal()
{
    Card tempTopCard = topCard;
    topCard = deck[++startingIndex];
    return tempTopCard;
}

int Deck::cardsLeft()
{
    return 52 - startingIndex;
}

void Deck::refreshDeck()
{
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii - 1].setCard('S', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[10].setCard('S', 'J');
    deck[11].setCard('S', 'Q');
    deck[12].setCard('S', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 12].setCard('D', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[23].setCard('D', 'J');
    deck[24].setCard('D', 'Q');
    deck[25].setCard('D', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 25].setCard('C', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[36].setCard('C', 'J');
    deck[37].setCard('C', 'Q');
    deck[38].setCard('C', 'K');
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 10; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii + 38].setCard('H', (ii + '0'));
    }
    deck[49].setCard('H', 'J');
    deck[50].setCard('H', 'Q');
    deck[51].setCard('H', 'K');
    startingIndex = 0;
    topCard = deck[startingIndex];
}

void Deck::showDeck()
{
    for (int ii = startingIndex; ii <= 51; ++ii)
    {
        deck[ii].displayCard();
    }
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(&deck[0], &deck[51], rand());
}
```

**Deck.h:**

```
#define Deck_H
#include "Card.h"

class Deck
{
public:
    Deck();

    Card deal();
    int cardsLeft();
    void refreshDeck();
    void showDeck();
    void shuffle();

private:
    Card deck[51];
    Card topCard;
    int startingIndex;
};
```

**Card.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Card::Card()
{
    suit = rank = 0;
}

int Card::getValue() 
{
    if (isdigit((int)rank))
        return rank - '0';
    else if (rank = 'J')
        return 11;
    else if (rank = 'Q')
        return 12;
    else
        return 13;
}

void Card::setCard(char newSuit, char newRank)
{
    suit = newSuit;
    rank = newRank;
}

void Card::displayCard()
{
    cout << rank << suit;
}
```

**Card.h:**

```
#define Card_H

class Card
{
public:
    Card(); 
    Card(char suit, char rank) : suit(suit), rank(rank) { }

    int getValue();
    void setCard(char suit, char rank);
    void displayCard();

private:
    char suit, rank;
};
```

Am getting these 4 **errors** that I can't find any way to solve:

```
1>d:\cecs 282\program 1\Card.h(10): error C2011: 'Card': 'class' type redefinition 
1>d:\cecs 282\program 1\Card.h(10): note: see declaration of 'Card' 
1>d:\cecs 282\program 1\Deck.h(22): error C2079: 'Deck::deck' uses undefined class 'Card' 
1>d:\cecs 282\program 1\Deck.h(23): error C2079: 'Deck::topCard' uses undefined class 'Card'
```

Someone please help as I have been looking for hours and it's getting really frustrating.

Comment: `#define Card_H` is only half of an include guard. You should read up on how to use them properly (though AFAIK most compilers support `#pragma once`)

Comment: with `define Card_H` you are misusing the "header guards" technique, you need more code to implement it correctly. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/header-guards-in-c) for more detail. As @UnholySheep suggests, `#pragma once` can be used with most compilers with the same result

Comment: Thanks, I was able to understand it and solve the problem!