# How can I fix sfml c++ code compilation error?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have created 2 .cpp files and 2 .header files

1. main.cpp (main .cpp file)
2. main.hpp (main header file)
3. game.cpp
4. game.hpp

I have used main.hpp components in game.hpp

Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "Window.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Ship{
public:
    Ship();
    ~Ship();

    int ship_x=400-28;
    int ship_y=600-55;

    sf::Texture ship_texture;
    sf::Sprite ship_sprite;

    Window *window = new Window();

    void Ship_Void(){
        if(window->event.type==sf::Event::KeyPressed){
            if(window->event.key.code==sf::Keyboard::D){
                if(ship_sprite.getPosition().x<=544)
                    ship_sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0.04, 0));
            }
            if(window->event.key.code==sf::Keyboard::A){
                if(ship_sprite.getPosition().x>=200)
                    ship_sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(-0.04, 0));
            }
            if(window->event.key.code==sf::Keyboard::W){
                if(ship_sprite.getPosition().y>=0)
                    ship_sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -0.04));
            }
            if(window->event.key.code==sf::Keyboard::S){
                if(ship_sprite.getPosition().y<=545)
                    ship_sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, 0.04));
            }
        }
    }

    void Keys(){
        ship_texture.loadFromFile("images/spaceship.png");
        ship_sprite.setTexture(ship_texture);
        ship_sprite.setPosition(ship_x, ship_y);
    }
};
```

Compilation command:

```
g++ Window.cpp -o game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Compilation error:

```
In file included from Ship.hpp:3,
                 from Window.cpp:2:
Window.hpp:5:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Window’
5     | class Window{
      |       ^~~~~~
In file included from Window.cpp:1:
Window.hpp:5:7: note: previous definition of ‘class Window’
5 | class Window{
```

Please help with fixing this error!

Comment: Add #include "game.h" in mainc.cpp ? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Your question lacks a description what you mean with "connect". As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, that you want to use in `main.cpp` some other variables, functions, classes, or other identifiers, which you **defined** in `game.cpp`.

The guideline is to put **declarations** of what you want to ever use externally in a header file.

So if you have this content of `game.cpp` (there are two **definitions** of functions):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace mygame {

    void a() { 
       std::cout << "A";
    }

    int b() {
       std::cout << "B";
       return 1;
    }

}
```

and you want to use `b()` in your main.cpp, then you add the **declaration** of `b` in a header `game.hpp`:

```
#ifndef GAME_HPP
#define GAME_HPP

int b();

#endif
```

then you include this header in your `main.cpp` by putting `#include "game.hpp"` on top of the `main.cpp` and thus you're allowed to use `b()` freely. So `main.cpp` might look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.hpp"

int main()
{
   std::cout << "MAIN";
   mygame::b();
   int x = mygame::b(); // remember that b() returns int
}
```

Notice that `game.hpp` also contains some ugly commands. They're not necessary to `#include` the file per se, but should be used to protect from *multiple definitions*. To find out more, look for [Header Guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/header-guards-in-c-and-c)

Also beware, as you technically can include a source file `game.cpp`, instead of `game.hpp`, but don't do that, since compiler will show you a plenty of puzzling messages. Just don't do that, until you know how preprocessor + compiler + linker work together.

Answer (score 2):

Put `#include "game.hpp"` on top of file main.cpp