# Repeted includes problem from header files in c++

Tags: c++, c, header

If I have ,let's say, a header file that contains `<iostream>` in it ,my main.cpp also contains `<iostream>`, this repetition could bring problems? If yes , how can I avoid this?

Comment: No, there aren't any problems due to correct [header guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/header-guards-in-c-and-c). If you have a concrete case, where you're facing problems give us a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there are no problems here.**

> [`[using.headers/2]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#using.headers-2): A translation unit may include library headers in any order ([lex.separate]). Each may be included more than once, with no effect different from being included exactly once, except that the effect of including either `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>` depends each time on the lexically current definition of `NDEBUG`.<sup>174</sup> **A translation unit may include library headers in any order** ([lex.separate]). **Each may be included more than once, with no effect different from being included exactly once**, except that the effect of including either `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>` depends each time on the lexically current definition of `NDEBUG`.<sup>174</sup>

Typically this is achieved using header guards, or a `#pragma once`.

I'm ignoring the caveat about `NDEBUG`, because you should not be setting or unsetting that using `#define` or `#undef`, but instead setting it (or not setting it) *en masse* across your build.