# How to fix this error redefinition of class date

Tags: c++

date.h file:

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
(3)    class Date {
    private:
        string date;
        string start_time;
        string stop_time;
    public:
        Date();
        Date(Date&);
        Date(string, string, string);
               //overloaded constructor;
        void set_date(string);
        void set_start_time(string);
            //void check_validity(string, string, string);
        void set_stop_time(string);
        string get_date();
        string get_start_time();
        string get_stop_time();
        void input();
        void print();
    
        ~Date();
    };
```

date.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;
Date::Date()
{
    //default constructor
    date = '\0';
    start_time = '\0';
    stop_time = '\0';
}
Date::Date(Date& d)
{
    //copy constructor
    date = d.date;
    start_time = d.start_time;
    stop_time = d.stop_time;
}
Date::Date(string date, string start_time, string stop_time)
{
    this->date = date;
    this->start_time = start_time;
    this->stop_time = stop_time;
}
void Date::set_date(string date)
{
    this->date = date;
}
void Date::set_start_time(string start_time)
{
    this->start_time = start_time;
}
void Date::set_stop_time(string stop_time)
{
    this->stop_time = stop_time;

}
string Date:: get_date()
{
    return this->date;
}
string Date::get_start_time()
{
    return this->start_time;
}
string Date::get_stop_time()
{
    return this->stop_time;
}
void Date::input()
{

    cout << "enter the date of the wedding event=";
    cin >> date;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the starting time of the wedding cermony=" << endl;
    cin >> start_time;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the ending time of the wedding cermony=" << endl;
    cin >> stop_time;
    cout << endl;

}
void Date::print()
{
    cout << "The Date of the wedding event is=" << this->date << endl;
    cout << "The Starting time of the weeding event is" << this->start_time << endl;
    cout << "The End time of the weeding event is" << this->stop_time << endl;
}
Date::~Date()
{
    //destructor
    date = '\0';
    start_time = '\0';
    stop_time = '\0';
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
#include "date.h"
#include "event.h"
#include "meeting.h"
#include "contact.h"
#include "appointment.h"
#include "calender.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Date d;
    d.set_date("15-12-2002");
    d.set_start_time("03:00 PM");
    d.set_stop_time("07:00 PM");
    Calender C;

    Event* A = new Appointment("0342-1447420", d,"wedding cermony");

    cout<<A->toString();
    Event* B = new Meeting("0342-1447421", d,"Disussion");
    cout<<B->toString();
    Calender c;
    c.addevent(A);
    c.addevent(B);
    int count = 0;
    Event** e = c.findEventsByKeyword("Disussion",count);
    cout<<e[0]->get_title();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> redefinition of class Date in date.h file at line number 3.

I try my best to solve it but I failed. What is wrong in it? It is in C++. Here I am attaching picture of error:

[image: error picture]

Comment: Do you have a `main.cpp` file that also `#include "date.h"`?

Comment: You probably want to add header guards. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/header-guards-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767068/header-guards-in-c-and-c)

Comment: FYI - `Date` doesn't need a user-defined copy constructor or user-defined destructor.  The more needless code you write, the more chance of bugs to occur.  Also, `std::string` already defaults to an empty string.  There is no need to assign `\0` to the string member variables.

Comment: you posted too much and too little code. Please read about [mcve]. Maybe you include `date.h` twice? But not in the posted code

Comment: Also, in the future, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i have put main.cpp in code. please check that

Comment: I suspect than at least one of event.h, meeting.h, contact.h, appointment.h, calender.h includes (directly or indirectly) date.h and you don't have [header_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include#Notes) (or `#pragma once`).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because in one of these header files:

```cpp
#include "event.h"
#include "meeting.h"
#include "contact.h"
#include "appointment.h"
#include "calender.h"
```

You have `#include "date.h"`

Consider this example:

*foo.h*

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int foo1;
};
```

*bar.h*

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

First, main.cpp `#include "foo.h"`, which copies the definition for `class Foo` into main.cpp. Then main.cpp `#include "bar.h"`, which `#include "foo.h"` itself. This copies contents of `#include "foo.h"` (including the definition for `class Foo`) into `#include "bar.h"` which then gets copied into main.cpp.

To resolve this, you have to use header guards, e.g in *foo.h*:

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
class Foo
{
    int foo1;
};
#endif FOO_H
```