# What is the conventional way of writing include guards?

Tags: c, header-files, include-guards

I usually write them as (for example.h):

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_H_
#define _EXAMPLE_H_
#include "example.h"
#endif
```

Does underscore convention matter?  I've seen conflicting information when I googled this.  Does the `_EXAMPLE_H_` even have to match the name of the header?

Comment: I believe this has already been thoroughly covered, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867559/naming-include-guards).

Comment: Or better yet, if you are looking for more extensive coverage of the topic consider http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#The__define_Guard . You can also read google style guide, just as a reference

Comment: The other is for *C++*, which a programming language distinct from C. The conventions are similar - for now - however, but the justification differs.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4867559/5740428

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Does underscore convention matter?
```

Yes. It matters.

Identifiers with a leading underscore followed upper case letter is reserved for implementation. So what you have would cause **undefined behaviour.**

The following is the C standard's specification for naming the identifiers ([C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its
>   associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers
>   listed in its associated future library directions subclause and
>   identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as
>   file scope identifiers.
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an
>   uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any
>   use.
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved
>   for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag
>   name spaces.
>
> — Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the
>   future library directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of
>   its associated headers is included; unless explicitly stated otherwise
>   (see 7.1.4). — All identifiers with external linkage in any of the
>   following subclauses (including the future library directions) and
>   errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external
>   linkage.184) — Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the
>   following subclauses (including the future library directions) is
>   reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope
>   in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines
>   an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as
>   allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name,
>   the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an
>   identifier in the first group listed above, the behavior is undefined.

Without violating any of the above, the include guard name can be anything and doesn't have to be the name of the header file. But usually the convention I have seen/used is to use same name as that of the header file name so that it doesn't cause any unnecessary confusion.

Comment: One common convention is to map the header name to uppercase and replace `.h` by `_H`, so the guard for `foobar.h` would be `FOOBAR_H`. If the name starts with 'e', for example `"elvis.h"`, then the guard macro would be `ELVIS_H` -- and macros starting with `E` and a digit or uppercase letter are reserved for use by `<errno.h>`. It's vanishingly unlikely that an implementation will define `ELVIS_H` as an error code, but you can avoid the possibility by using a convention like `H_HEADER_NAME` rather than `HEADER_NAME_H`.

Answer (score -2):

There is no absolute requirement as to how include guards are named.  It does not have to match the header name.  I have seen (and used myself) some that use a UUID, basically composed of a randomly generated hexadecimal string.

Technically as KingsIndian said, identifiers beginning with underscores are reserved:

> The rules, paraphrased from ANSI Sec. 4.1.2.1, are:
>
> ```
> 1. All identifiers beginning with an underscore followed
>    by an upper-case letter or another underscore are always
>    reserved (all scopes, all namespaces).
> 2. All identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved
>    for ordinary identifiers (functions, variables, typedefs, enumeration
>    constants) with file scope.
> ...
> ```
>
> [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 1.29](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html)

Maybe the new ISO C11 (?) standard relaxes these rules, but that's been the bottom line for a while.

Comment: -1. That's not the rule about underscores. And if you don't start with an underscore but use an UUID, you're likely to start with a numeral.

Comment: Not a raw UUID but something like `INCLUDED_AF3430340AB3012FE0DEADBEEF`.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by either a second underscore or an uppercase letter are reserved for any use. All identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.  It's good to know the exact rules, but it's wise to be conservative and just avoid defining *anything* starting with an underscore.

Comment: No, ISO C11 has not relaxed the rules.