# How to forward declare a class which is in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to use forward declarations in header files to reduce the number of `#include` used and hence reduce dependencies when users include my header file.

However, I am unable to forward declare where namespaces are used.  See example below.

File `a.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __A_HPP__
#define __A_HPP__

namespace ns1 {

   class a {
   public:
      a(const char* const msg);

      void talk() const;

   private:
      const char* const msg_;
   };
}

#endif //__A_HPP__
```

File `a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"

using namespace ns1;

a::a(const char* const msg) : msg_(msg) {}

void a::talk() const { 
   std::cout << msg_ << std::endl; 
}
```

File `consumer.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __CONSUMER_HPP__
#define __CONSUMER_HPP__

// How can I forward declare a class which uses a namespace
//doing this below results in error C2653: 'ns1' : is not a class or namespace name
// Works with no namespace or if I use using namespace ns1 in header file
// but I am trying to reduce any dependencies in this header file
class ns1::a;

class consumer
{
public:
   consumer(const char* const text) : a_(text) {}
   void chat() const;

private:
   a& a_;
};

#endif // __CONSUMER_HPP__
```

Implementation file `consumer.cpp`:

```
#include "consumer.hpp"
#include "a.hpp"

consumer::consumer(const char* const text) : a_(text) {}

void consumer::chat() const {
   a_.talk();
}
```

Test file `main.cpp`:

```
#include "consumer.hpp"

int main() {
   consumer c("My message");
   c.chat();
   return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Here is my very contrived working code using the answer below.

File `a.hpp`:

```
#ifndef A_HPP__
#define A_HPP__

#include <string>

namespace ns1 {

   class a {
   public:
      void set_message(const std::string& msg);
      void talk() const;

   private:
      std::string msg_;
   };

} //namespace

#endif //A_HPP__
```

File `a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.hpp"

void ns1::a::set_message(const std::string& msg) {
    msg_ = msg;
}
void ns1::a::talk() const { 
   std::cout << msg_ << std::endl; 
}
```

File `consumer.hpp`:

```
#ifndef CONSUMER_HPP__
#define CONSUMER_HPP__

namespace ns1
{
   class a;
}

class consumer
{
public:
   consumer(const char* text);
   ~consumer();
   void chat() const;

private:
   ns1::a* a_;
};

#endif // CONSUMER_HPP__
```

File `consumer.cpp`:

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "consumer.hpp"

consumer::consumer(const char* text) {
   a_ = new ns1::a;
   a_->set_message(text);
}
consumer::~consumer() {
   delete a_;
}
void consumer::chat() const {
   a_->talk();
}
```

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include "consumer.hpp"

int main() {
   consumer c("My message");
   c.chat();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use names starting with two underscores or an underscore and a capital letter for macros -- these are reserved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307540/include-guard-conventions-in-c/17307796#17307796

Comment: this is not just a namespace issue. consumer.cpp is aware that there is a class type a, but it is not aware of the specifics. You try to invoke the method a::talk(), which the compiler knows nothing about. You still need to #include "a.hpp" from consumer.cpp so the compiler is aware of the classes full interface. This #include will be internal to the .cpp hence will not be "spread around" through consumer.hpp.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To forward declare class type `a` in a namespace `ns1`:

```
namespace ns1
{
    class a;
}
```

To forward declare a type in multiple level of namespaces:

```
namespace ns1
{
  namespace ns2
  {
    //....
     namespace nsN
     {
        class a;
     }
    //....    
  }
}
```

Your are using `a` a member of `consumer` which means it needs concrete type, your forward declaration won't work for this case.

Comment: +1: Its easily 10 years since I wrote C++ in anger but I immediately knew the answer to this, simply re-declare the namespace. I'm quite pleased I remembered that, I've forgotten so much else . . .

Comment: @Thomas, I just tried that and got `error C3083: 'ns1': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type`

Comment: @Thomas  I believe that only works if the namespace already exists.

Comment: @Iron Not only that namespace must exist, but the class must be declared in it, in which case there's little point redeclaring the class outside of namespace.

Answer (score 36):

For nested namespaces, since C++17, you can do

```
namespace ns1::ns2::nsN
{
  class a;
}
```

Comment: How about just `class ns1::ns2::nsN::a`?

Comment: That's a relief, the old form was so long when a class was nestled.

Comment: It would definitely be nice, @santahopar, but it isn't valid sytax (yet?).  Might be worth proposing for the next C++ standard, either as `class ns1::ns2::nsN::a`, or as `namespace ns1::ns2::nsN::class a`, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

Apart to forward-declare the class from within its namespace (as @billz says), remember to either *use* (prepend) that namespace when referring to the forward-declared class, or add a `using` clause:

```
// B.h
namespace Y { class A; } // full declaration of
// class A elsewhere

namespace X {
    using Y::A;   // <------------- [!]
    class B {
        A* a; // Y::A
    };
}
```

---

Ref: [Namespaces and Forward Class Declarations](https://www.epstudiossoftware.com/namespaces-and-forward-class-declarations/)