# declaration does not declare anything : warning?

Tags: c, struct, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    struct emp
    {
        struct address
        {
              int a;
        };
        struct address a1;
    };
}
```

This code shows a warning:-

*warning : declaration does not declare anything (enabled by default)*

Where as the following code shows no warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    struct emp
    {
        struct address
        {
             int a;
        }a1;
    };
}
```

Why 'warning' is displayed in the first code only?

Comment: can u pls post your include statements too and macros if u used any?

Comment: Is your struct empty as you shown?

Comment: @rullof : ya but data members do not make any difference in this case

Comment: Please add some members to make the question more clear for people answering.

Comment: The warning is not related to the fact that the `address` struct doesn't have any variables, but the fact that its declaration statement doesn't define any variables.

Comment: @juan.facorro : but after the `struct address`, I have defined a variable.

Comment: @kevingomes Yes, you have, but not in the `struct address {};` statement, which precedes `struct address a1;`, this is why the compiler warns you about a statement that doesn't declare a variable in the `emp` struct.

Comment: @juan.facorro : then why the compiler does not show any warning for `struct emp` as I have also not created any variable of `struct emp` type.

Comment: @kevingomes Just updated the question to explain why the `emp` is not causing a warning.

Comment: wow..........may I know the reason for the downvote????????????

Comment: There is no reason for defining a structure inside another as it's no longer accessible outside of the parent structure scope. (I didn't down voted).

Comment: @rullof : I know that, but my question was not about the application of defining a structure within another.

Comment: You should stick to the role otherwise you should expect errors.

Comment: @rullof : my question was about that error only

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why the compiler is showing the warning is because it doesn't see a name for the variable of type `address` you defined for the `emp` struct, even though you **do** declare something using `address` on the next line, but I guess the compiler is not smart enough to figure that out.

As you showed, this produces a warning:

```
struct emp {
  struct address {}; // This statement doesn't declare any variable for the emp struct.
  struct address a1;
};
```

But not this:

```
struct emp {
  struct address {} a1; // This statement defines the address struct and the a1 variable.
};
```

Or this:

```
struct address {};

struct emp {
  struct address a1; //the only statement declare a variable of type struct address
};
```

The `struct emp {}` doesn't show any warnings since this statement is not inside a struct defintion block. If you did put it inside one of those then the compiler will show a warning for that as well. The following will show two warnings:

```
struct emp {
  struct phone {};
  struct name {};
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason the warning is displayed is that the first excerpt is not proper C - it has a constraint violation that a standards-compliant C compiler **must** produce a diagnostisc message for. It violates the [C11 6.7.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p2):

> **Constraints**
>
> 2. A *struct-declaration* that does not declare an anonymous structure or anonymous union shall contain a *struct-declarator-list*.

Meaning that it is OK to write

```
struct foo {
    struct {
          int a;
    };
};
```

since the inner `struct` declares an *anonymous* structure, i.e. it is not named.

But in your example the `struct address` has a name - `address` - and therefore it **must** have a declarator list after the closing brace - declarator list being for example `a1` as in your example, or more complex `foo, *bar, **baz[23][45]`.

Comment: I don't think so, what you quote means (in a not very precise way): a struct with a name must has members which have not only types but also declarators(variable names), what you quote has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of a structure definition is:

```
struct identifier {
    type member_name;

    // ...

};
```

If you add an identifier just after the closing curly brace, you're declaring a variable with that defined struct.

In your first example the compiler consider the `address` struct as member type. it's like if you writes:

```
struct identifier {

    type ; // No member name is specified
    type a1;

    // ...

}
```

But in the second example you specified the member name:

```
struct identifier {

    type a1; // Member name specified

    // ...

}
```

And here is an example of the warning: http://ideone.com/KrnYiE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had the same warning because the structure name was previously used and changing the structure name solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Going to also throw this out there that this error may also show up if you don't properly forward declare types found in other namespaces.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001722/1330381

Example

```
namespace A {

// forward declarations
namespace X {
namespace Y {
class MyType;
}
}

namespace B {

class Foo() {
    void methodBar(const X::Y::MyType& mt);
}
}
```

Comment: This is not C and doesn't solve the question.