# GCC turning off "warning: declaration does not declare anything"

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a flag I can pass to gcc to disable this warning? I am aware of what it does, but it does not matter for my program.

Edit: I would like to merely disable the warning, keeping the code as it is.
Compiling the following code generates the warning:

```
struct post{
  unsigned int isImg : 1;
  struct img{
    char *name;
    char *url;
    int likes;
  };

  unsigned int isTxt : 1;
  struct text{
     char*text;
     int likes;
  };
  union Data{
    struct img Img;
    struct text Txt;
  } data;
};
```

The gcc version I am using is 5.4.0

Comment: @AnttiHaspala why would you need a code?

Comment: @Michi I was about to ask the same thing, but: I haven't succeeded in reproducing the OP's error message, so I haven't made any progress in figuring out how to turn it off.  A sample of the OP's actual code, hopefully triggering the same specific warning, would help.

Comment: @AneeshDurg Can you give us an example of a declaration that's triggering the warning? Can you tell us which version of gcc you're using? (Invoke `gcc --version` to find out.)

Comment: Okay, I've added some code!

Comment: Maybe you could `grep` the warning out of the result

Comment: Clang-LLVM shows the warning as “-Wmissing-declarations”, and using “-Wno-missing-declarations” disables it. [You could try the same switch with GCC.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) That documentation says it is for global functions without prior declarations, but it is worth a try.

Comment: You should fix your code [**as it has a constraint violation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610637/declaration-does-not-declare-anything-warning/49353894#49353894) i.e. it is not correct C code - and certainly not a compiler bug, @M.M.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are right... although I'd still say the behaviour following the message is somewhat unintuitive (it proceeds as if the struct type were declared and everything else is fine)

Comment: I see how this isn't correct C code, changing the way I'm generating this code is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at:

```
struct post{
    unsigned int isImg : 1;
    struct img
    {
        char *name;
        char *url;
        int likes;
    };

    unsigned int isTxt : 1;

    struct text
    {
        char*text;
        int likes;
    };

    union Data
    {
        struct img Img;
        struct text Txt;
    } data;
};
```

I see a few problems:

1. the definition of first 32 bit bitmap, only one bit defined
2. the 'img' struct is 12 bytes+4bytes filler
3. the definition of second 32 bit bitmap, only one bit defined
4. the 'text' struct is 8 bytes+8bytes filler
5. the union, composed of the two prior struct types
6. all defined with an enclosing struct

This is very poor organization of the data declarations.

suggest:

```
struct img  //32bits
{
    char *name;
    char *url;
    int   likes;
};

struct text //32bits
{
     char *text;
     int   likes;
};

union Data  // 32bits
{
    struct img  Img;
    struct text Text;
};


struct post //5*32bits
{
  unsigned int isImg : 1;
  struct img   image;
  unsigned int isTxt : 1;
  struct text  Text;
  union Data   data;
};
```

even with the above (which compiles with no errors/warnings) there is still the problem that a bitmap ordering is implementation defined, so you do not know, without testing, if those defined bits are the MSB or the LSB of the bitmap.