# How to handle namespaces in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, qt5

I have created a DialogBox in QtDesigner

```
//---------- *.H
namespace Ui {
   class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
   ~MyDialog();

 private:
    Ui::MyDialog* ui;  
};
```

and its source

```
// --------- *.CPP
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //..
}
```

I would like to structure that in a certain namespace encapsulation, so that I have **com::example::mydialogs::MyDialog** like:

```
//---------- *.H
namespace com {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs {

namespace Ui {
   class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
   ~MyDialog();

 private:
    Ui::MyDialog* ui;  
};
}}} //namespace closing
```

and its source

```
// --------- *.CPP
namespace com {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs {

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //..
}
}}} //namespace closing
```

but my compiler complains about that with a message:

> C:\MyProjects\Test\com\example\mydialogs\MyDialog.h:29: Error: forward
>   declaration of 'class com::example::mydialogs::Ui::MyDialog'  class
>   MyDialog;

The namespace Ui was added by Qt automatically. How can I use my namespace structure properly?

Comment: Line 7 is in the wrong namespace. `class MyDialog;` forward declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to forward declare a namespace, you need to use the following canonical syntax:

```
namespace ns1
{
   namespace ns2
   {
   //....
     namespace nsN
     {
     class a;
     }
  //....    
  }
}
```

The above code snippet was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001700/how-to-forward-declare-a-class-which-is-in-a-namespace). So in your case, you need to close the namespaces where the forward declaration is.

```
namespace com {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs {

namespace Ui {
   class MyDialog;
}

} // mydialogs
} // example
} // com

namespace com {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs {

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
   ~MyDialog();

private:
    Ui::MyDialog* ui;  
};
}}} //namespace closing
```

Your implementation code looks correct. Make those slight changes to the header file and it should compile.

I have not tested this code. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I just tried that out what you wrote me and get **C:\MyProjects\Test\com\example\mydialogs\MyDialog.h:27: Error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MyDialog'
   ui(new Ui::MyDialog)**

Comment: @RalfWickum Did you include the header file in the cpp file?

Comment: Yes I did **#incldue "mydialog.h"** in the mydialog.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Just leave outside `Ui::MyDialog`

```
namespace Ui {
   class MyDialog;
}

namespace com {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs {
...
```

Because the forward declaration Ui::MyDialog is created by uic tool when processing your ui file, it cannot being included in your declaration.

Comment: `// .. HPP
#include <Includes>

namespace Ui {
class MyDialog;
}

using namespace other::namespaces;

namespace com     {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs  {

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
  ~MyDialog();
  //..
}`
and the cource
`// .. CPP
#include "mydialog.h"

namespace com     {
namespace example {
namespace mydialogs  {

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  //..
}
Same invalid use of type 'class Ui::Mydialog' and  forward declaration class Ui:MyDialog