# How to forward declare an enum from a namespace?

Tags: c++, enums

For example :

```cpp
namespace MYGAMESTATE {
    enum class GameState {
        GAME
    };
}
```

How would I forward declare this enum in another file, since it is in a namespace?

Would it be one of these?

```
extern enum class MYGAMESTATE::GameState;
extern enum class GameState;
enum class GameState;
enum class MYGAMESTATE::GameState;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward declare a class which is in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001700/how-to-forward-declare-a-class-which-is-in-a-namespace)

Comment: Why do want to forward-declare it in the first place? What are you trying to achieve by that? (It doesn't work for a reason, and while it can be made to work, I doubt you actually need it)

Comment: Since you are not providing a *storage type*, you cannot forward declare the enum.  If it had a storage type, you could do `namespace MYGAMESTATE { enum class GameState : int; }`

Comment: You can't. C++ just forbids this because it's pointless. Just include the header file with the declaration of the enum where you need it.

Comment: What do you mean storage type @Eljay

Comment: @SergeyA I'd like to hide as much code as possible in my header (PImpl)

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you so much

Comment: *q.v.* [enumeration declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Answer (score 0):

(Mostly compiling an answer from the comments)

If you have to use the enum as in your example, without storage type, you can not do that.

But if you are free to add the storage type, then you can:

Enum (using `uint8_t` as storage type):

```
namespace MYGAMESTATE {
    enum class GameState : uint8_t {
        GAME
    };
}
```

Forward declaration:

```
namespace MYGAMESTATE { enum class GameState : uint8_t; }
```