# MISRA C 2012 - Rule 21.1 - Macros starting with underscore

Tags: c, lint, misra

Rule 21.1 in MISRA C 2012 states that

> **#define and #undef shall not be used on a reserved identifier or reserved macro name**
>
> This rule applies to identifier or macro beginning with an underscore
>
> **Rationale**:
>
> Removing or changing the meaning of a reserved macro may result in
> undefined bahaviour

I don't understand why macro's name shall not start with an unerscore, even if it is not a reserved macro? For example in my header files:

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_
#define __MY_HEADER_
```

or in a library I'm using:

```
#define __I volatile const
```

Should I change all my code and the library I'm using (which is a big library) in order to conform to this rule or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: `even if it is not a reserved macro?` it *could* be used  in an other implementation, or even in an other version of this implementation.

Comment: OK. So how can I solve it? It's hard to change '__I' in all of the library modules!

Comment: User code should not use leading underscores; thay are reserved for the implementation and the libraries. So you should only change *your own* code, removing all leading underscores.from `#define _xyz ...` And dont change the librariy headers. These are made by people who are supposed to know what they are doing. 9You could, of course *refer* to macros in the library headers, but never (re) *define* them)

Comment: The underscore naming is a C standard requirement, not a MISRA requirement.

Comment: For whatever reason a compiler may predefine `__MY_HEADER_`. So, the group
that is controlled by `#ifndef __MY_HEADER_` is skipped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to C standard (section 7.1.3), *all* identifiers starting with `_[A_Z]` or `__` are reserved. As they are reserved, common sense and rule 21 forbid you to modify (redefine or undefine) them (or create your own).

Thus, you should change your code to **not** using leading underscores even in include guards not to mention your macros.

Some further reading can be found e.g. here: [Include guard conventions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307540/include-guard-conventions-in-c)