# Designing .h and a .cpp file C++ : Errors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a Matrix program that makes a n*m matrix of integers using vectors of vectors of integers. But I'm having trouble doing this as I'm fairly new to C++. I have started implementing my program, but I'm getting a whole bunch of errors that I can't figure out why. Also, this is my 1st time using a .h and vectors so please be gentle :) .

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H 

#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    public:
        Matrix( );
        Matrix(int r, int c);
        void setRow(vector<int> row, int r);
        void setColumn(vector<int> col, int c);
        int getRow();
        int getCol();
        void output();
        double average();
    private:
        int row, column;
        vector< vector<int> > matrix;
};

#endif
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int row,column;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter number of column: ";
    cin >> column;
    Matrix matrix(row,column);
    matrix.output();

}

Matrix::Matrix():row(3), column(3){
    matrix = vector<vector<int> >(row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        matrix[i] = vector<int>(column);
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c): row(r), column(c){
    matrix = vector<vector<int> >(r);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        matrix[i] = vector<int>(c);
    }
}

void Matrix::setRow(vector<int> row, int r){
    if (r <= row){
        if (row.size <= column){
            for (int i = 0; i < row.size; i++){
                matrix[r][i] = row[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::setColumn(vector<int> col, int c){
    if (c <= column){
        if (col.size <= row){
            for (int i = 0; i < col.size; i++){
                matrix[i][c] = col[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::output(){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }
}
```

OK so the above is the fixed version of my previous code, but now I'm getting this error:

Errors:

```
Matrix.cpp: In member function ‘void Matrix::setRow(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int)’:
Matrix.cpp:32: error: no match for ‘operator<=’ in ‘r <= row’
Matrix.cpp:33: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
Matrix.cpp:34: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
Matrix.cpp: In member function ‘void Matrix::setColumn(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int)’:
Matrix.cpp:43: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
Matrix.cpp:44: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
```

Comment: You don't need to have that `#include<iostream>` in the header and it will slow down your compiles times by a lot since `iostream` is such a huge header.

Comment: Important information: [Naming Include Guards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4867559/103167) and [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/103167)

Comment: You should never put `using namespace std;` in the global part of a header file (and preferably not anywhere else).

Comment: @Galik, so i should remove it, but do i need to include it anywhere else in the .h file?

Comment: You can put it in your class definition or else put your class in its own namespace and add it in there. Or you can just qualify your `std::vector` with `std::`.

Comment: Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1. You named the include guard and the class with the same name. As such, the preprocessor will completely mess up by replacing `Matrix` with the empty string. Replace:

   ```
   #ifndef Matrix
   #define Matrix
   ```

   with:

   ```
   #ifndef Matrix_h
   #define Matrix_h
   ```

   or anything else. Trailing `_H` and ALL CAPS are a common expedient to avoid naming collisions. For instance, you could use:

   ```
   #ifndef MATRIX_H
   #define MATRIX_H
   ```
2. You forgot to import Vector class. Add at the top of `Matrix.h`:

   ```
   #include <vector>
   ```
3. You can't initialize a vector of vectors with `matrix(0,0,0,0,0,0)`. Just omit that part. `int` elements in a `vector` already default to zero.
4. You did not provide a constructor which accepts an integer and a vector, which would be used at line 20 of `Matrix.cpp`:

   ```
   Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c): row(r), column(c){
       matrix(r, vector<int>(c));
       // ....
   }
   ```

   Fix it like:

   ```
   Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c): row(r), column(c){
       matrix = vector<vector<int> >(r);
       for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
           matrix[i] = vector<int>(c);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: But don't use double underscores or underscore followed by capital letter, because those are reserved names.

Comment: That still looks like a double underscore :(

Comment: @BenVoigt leading underscores are reserved, trailing undescores are fine, AFAIK. Maybe you are looking to an old/cached version? Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/103167)

Comment: ok thanks, how would i initialize the size of the multidimensional vector in my constructor?

Answer (score 1):

when you define `Matrix`, you define it to nothing, so `class Matrix{` evaluates into `class{`, as well as all occurances of `Matrix` inside the class itself.

This is because of preprocessor running the `#if` blocks before compiling code, and replacing all occurances of found `#define`s into given strings, which is in your case, empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your header gaurds first:-

```
#ifndef Matrix
#define Matrix
```

it resembles class name. make it something like

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_
#define __MATRIX_
```

Comment: But don't use double underscores or underscore followed by capital letter, because those are reserved names.

Comment: @a22asin: Yes it would... until you come across code that uses `M` as a variable name, and suddenly breaks.  I left a comment on the question with a link to good recommendations.