# C++ Separate header and source file

Tags: c++, header-files, text-editor

I'm new to C++ and so far I've had all code in one and the same file.
Now as I'm progressing, I need to separate my code in to source and header files which I'm not very familiar with.

I can make it work with simple tasks, but in this program that I'm now trying to divide in to separate files gives me an error, while when I have it all in one file I can compile it.

I get stuck on the error message

```
main.cpp:10:1: error: unknown type name 'textEditor'
textEditor siEditor;
```

If someone could explain why I'm running in to this error and how to prevent it would be appreciated. I read that it could be related to duplicated declarations, but I don't understand from where.

This is how my main.cpp looks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "textData.h"
#include "textEditor.h"

textData siData;
textEditor siEditor;

int main() 
{
    cout << "\nWelcome to siEdit!" << endl;
    while (true) 
    {
        cout << "\nWhat would you like to do? \nNew file = n, Append = a, View = v, Quit = q: ";
        string toDo;
        cin >> toDo;

        if (toDo == "n")
        {
            siEditor.openText();
            cout << "Now editing the file: " << siData.fileName.c_str() << endl;
            cout << "Type '=!' to stop editing and save. \n " << endl;
            siEditor.writeText();
        }

        else if (toDo == "a")
        {
            siEditor.appendTextOpen();
            cout << "Now appending text: " << siData.appendTextfileName.c_str() << endl;
            cout << "Type '=!' to stop editing and save changes. \n " << endl;
            siEditor.appendText();
        }

        else if (toDo == "v")
        {
            siEditor.readText();
            cout << "\n";
        }

        else if (toDo == "q")
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else 
        {
            cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

siEdit.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "textData.h"
#include "textEditor.h"

textData siData;

class textEditor
{
    public: 
    void openText()
    {   
        //when associated file is open. 
        while (siData.siFile.is_open())
        {
            siData.siFile.close();
        }
        cout << "\nWhat do you want to call your file? ";
        cin >> siData.fileName;

        //Creates / Opens fileEditor
        const char* path = siData.fileName.c_str();
        siData.siFile.open(path);
    }

    void writeText()
    {
        bool editing = true;
        bool hasEditing = false;

        while (editing == true)
        {
            //Get user input
            string input = " ";
            getline(cin, input);
            string yesNo;

            if (input == "=!") 
                {   
                    cout << "Would you like to save the file? Y/N" << endl;
                    cin >> yesNo;

                    if (yesNo == "Y")
                    {
                        cout << "Filed saved: " << siData.fileName.c_str();
                        editing = false;
                    }   

                    else if (yesNo == "N")
                    {
                        cout << "No changes have been saved. Exiting." << endl;
                        hasEditing = false;
                        editing = false;
                        siData.siFile.clear();
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid input. Type '=! to exit." << endl;

                    }
                }       

            else
            {
                siData.siFile << input;
                siData.siFile << endl;
                hasEditing = true;
            }
        }
    }


    void readText()
    {
        string line;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of your file: ";
        cin >> siData.fileName;
        cout << "\n";
        const char* path = siData.fileName.c_str();

        // input file stream
        //Internal stream buffer which performes I/O on file.
        ifstream siFileRead(path);
        if(siFileRead.is_open())
        {
            while(getline(siFileRead,line))
            {
                cout << line << endl;
                siData.siFile << line;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Unable to open file. Confirm name and file location.";
        }
    }

    // open the existing text file
    void appendTextOpen()
    {
        while (siData.siFileAppend.is_open())
        {
            // erase previous text
            siData.siFileAppend.clear();
            // close the input text file
            siData.siFileAppend.close();
        }

        cout << "\nEnter the name of the file: ";
        //find file name.
        cin >> siData.appendTextfileName;

        //Makes / Opens file
        const char* path = siData.appendTextfileName.c_str();
        siData.siFileAppend.open(path, fstream::app);
    }

    //add text together with previous input.
    void appendText()
    {
        bool editing = true;
        bool hasEditing = false;

        while (editing == true)
        {
            //Gets user input
            string input = " ";
            getline(cin, input);

            if (input == "=!")
            {
                if (hasEditing == true)
                {
                    cout << "File saved: " << siData.appendTextfileName.c_str() << endl;
                    editing = false;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                siData.siFileAppend << input;
                siData.siFileAppend << endl;
                hasEditing = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

textData.h:

```
#ifndef SIEDITOR_H
#define SIEDITOR_H

class textData
{
    public: 
        string fileName;
        string appendTextfileName;
        ofstream siFile;
        ofstream siFileAppend;
};

#endif
```

textEditor.h:

```
#ifndef SIEDITOR_H
#define SIEDITOR_H

class textEditor
{
    public: 
    void openText()
    void writeText()
    void readText()
    void appendTextOpen()
    void appendText()
};


#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't be re-defining your classes in your cpp files; you should be implementing the methods. You should ideally have `textData.cpp` and `textEditor.cpp` too otherwise I don't think it will get included properly.

Comment: I think there may be working examples of code split into header and implementation files out there on the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

Class must be defined only once.

Move class definition to separated header file (join togather both content of your same name class: fields and methods):

```
// textEditor.h
#pragma once
class textEditor {
  void appendText();
private:
    string fileName;
}
```

Move class methods to separate source file:

```
// textEditor.cpp
#include "textEditor.h"
void textEditor::appendText() {
   // ... impl
}
```

And in the main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include "textEditor.h"

textEditor siEditor;

int main() 
{
  siEditor.appendText();
}
```

Comment: *"Class must be declared only once."* - No, they can be declared as often as you wish. They must be **defined** only once. `class textEditor { /* ... */
};` is a definition, not a declaration. `class textEditor;` would be a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same include guard in both header files, namely `SIEDITOR_H`. That prevents the second header's contents from being included. Use `#pragma once` instead of include guard symbols.

`#pragma once` is a *de facto* standard that's [supported by all compilers of practical interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).

In your implementation file don't repeat the class definition. Just define the declared member functions. And `static` data members, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the preprocessor does. It runs separately for every `*.cpp` file and processes all your `#include`, `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif` statements.

This is the start of the your `main.cpp`:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> #include "textData.h"
> #include "textEditor.h"
>
> textData siData;
> textEditor siEditor;
> ```

How would you preprocess this if you were a preprocessor?<sup>[*]</sup> You would probably start with the `#include` statements. The intermediate result would be:

```
// contents of <iostream>...
// contents of <fstream>...

using namespace std;

#ifndef SIEDITOR_H
#define SIEDITOR_H

class textData
{
    public: 
        string fileName;
        string appendTextfileName;
        ofstream siFile;
        ofstream siFileAppend;
};

#endif

#ifndef SIEDITOR_H
#define SIEDITOR_H

class textEditor
{
    public: 
    void openText()
    void writeText()
    void readText()
    void appendTextOpen()
    void appendText()
};


#endif

textData siData;
textEditor siEditor;
```

Now let's inspect this intermediate result:

```
// contents of <iostream>...
// contents of <fstream>...

using namespace std;

#ifndef SIEDITOR_H // <--- true, SIEDITOR_H is not defined, don't skip until #endif
#define SIEDITOR_H // <--- OK, SIEDITOR_H is now defined

class textData
{
    public: 
        string fileName;
        string appendTextfileName;
        ofstream siFile;
        ofstream siFileAppend;
};

#endif // <--- end of block started by #ifndef SIEDITOR_H

#ifndef SIEDITOR_H // <--- false, SIEDITOR_H is defined, skip until #endif
#define SIEDITOR_H

class textEditor
{
    public: 
    void openText()
    void writeText()
    void readText()
    void appendTextOpen()
    void appendText()
};


#endif // <--- end of block started by #ifndef SIEDITOR_H

textData siData;
```

The result of the preprocessing turns out to be:

```
// contents of <iostream>...
// contents of <fstream>...

using namespace std;

class textData
{
    public: 
        string fileName;
        string appendTextfileName;
        ofstream siFile;
        ofstream siFileAppend;
};

textData siData;
textEditor siEditor; // error, unknown type textEditor
```

---

This explains the specific error message you have been asking about. The solution is to use a different include guard in every header file. You must choose completely **unique include guard names**. In big projects, this can become difficult. Here's some reading material:

- [Naming Include Guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867559/naming-include-guards)
- [Is #pragma once part of the C++11 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696115/is-pragma-once-part-of-the-c11-standard)

---

Nevertheless, there are more errors in your code:

First of all, **your header files assume a lot**. They assume that someone else already included the necessary standard headers to get `std::string` and `std::ofstream`. They *also* assume that someone else has already used `using namespace std;` or `using std::string; using std::ofstream;`.

That's very bad practice. Your header file should include the standard headers it needs, and just **spell out the complete names** (no `using namespace std;`).

In addition to that, it should use **standard headers which are *guaranteed* to contain what you need**. If you need `std::string`, then include `<string>`.

Standard headers *may* include other standard headers, but there are only very few guaranteed indirect inclusions (I am too lazy to look up in the standard if `<iostream>` implies `<string>`, but I guess it does not.)

Here is an example:

**textEditor.h:**

```
#ifndef SI_TEXT_DATA_H
#define SI_TEXT_DATA_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class textData
{
    public: 
        std::string fileName;
        std::string appendTextfileName;
        std::ofstream siFile;
        std::ofstream siFileAppend;
};

#endif
```

---

Finally, you **redefine your `textEditor` class** in `siEdit.cpp`. That's not allowed. You should instead declare the member functions in the `*.h` file inside of the class definition, and define the member functions in the `*.cpp` file.

`textEditor.h` should look like this:

```
#ifndef SI_TEXT_EDITOR_H
#define SI_TEXT_EDITOR_H

class textEditor // class definition begins
{
    public: 
    void openText();       // declaration of member function
    void writeText();      // declaration of member function
    void readText();       // declaration of member function
    void appendTextOpen(); // declaration of member function
    void appendText();     // declaration of member function

}; // class definition ends

#endif
```

And `siEdit.cpp` should look like this:

```
#include "textData.h"
#include "textEditor.h"

textData siData;

void textEditor::openText() // definition of a member function begins
{   
    // ...

} // definition of a member function ends

// other definitions
```

---

Your global variables (like `textData siData;`) are not a very good idea, either, especially seeing as how they are not wrapped in anonymous namespaces.

---

<sup>[*] *An actual preprocessor may not technically work like this, but you can picture it that way.*</sup>