# LNK2019 and LNK1120 when separating class into header and source file

Tags: c++, linker

I am currently having to make a project using multiple files for the first time. Using headers and such to make sure that the main function is able to identify the other ones. I have student.h and degree.h both included in main and it runs fine until I ask it to use the constructor for student in which case it immediatly breaks and gives me the errors.

Code if it's helpful

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Student::Student(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,enum DegreeProgram)" (??0Student@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000HHHHW4DegreeProgram@@@Z) referenced in function main   IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2    S:\School\Programming Projects\Student Roster\IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2\IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2\main.obj    1       


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2    S:\School\Programming Projects\Student Roster\IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2\x64\Debug\IsaiahBullockStudentRosterV2.exe   1
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "degree.h"
#include "student.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Student student1("A1", "John", "Smith", "John1989@gm ail.com", 20, 30, 35, 40, SECURITY);
```

degree.h

```
#pragma once
enum DegreeProgram {
    SECURITY, NETWORK, SOFTWARE
};
```

student.h

```
#pragma once
#include "degree.h"
using std::string;
class Student {
public:
    Student(string iStudentID, string iFName, string iLName, string iEmail, int iAge, int daysToCom1, int daysToCom2, int daysToCom3, DegreeProgram iDegree);
    void setID(string iStudentID);
    void setFName(string iFName);
    void setLName(string iLName);
    void setEmail(string iEmail);
    void setAge(int iAge);
    void setComArray(int daysToCom1, int daysToCom2, int daysToCom3);
    void setDegree(DegreeProgram iDegree);
    string getID();
    string getFName();
    string getLName();
    string getEmail();
    int getAge();
    int getDay1();
    int getDay2();
    int getDay3();
    double getAvgDays();
    DegreeProgram getDegree();
};
```

student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "degree.h"

using std::string;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(string iStudentID, string iFName, string iLName, string iEmail,  int iAge, int daysToCom1, int daysToCom2, int daysToCom3, DegreeProgram iDegree) {
        setID(iStudentID);
        setFName(iFName);
        setLName(iLName);
        setAge(iAge);
        setEmail(iEmail);
        setComArray(daysToCom1, daysToCom2, daysToCom3);
        setDegree(iDegree);
    }

    void setID(string iStudentID) {
        string studentID = iStudentID;
    }
    void setFName(string iFName) {
        string fname = iFName;
    }
    void setLName(string iLName) {
        string lname = iLName;
    }
    void setEmail(string iEmail) {
        email = iEmail;
    }
    void setAge(int iAge) {
        age = iAge;
    }
    void setComArray(int daysToCom1, int daysToCom2, int daysToCom3) {
        numDaysToCom[0] = (daysToCom1);
        numDaysToCom[1] = (daysToCom2);
        numDaysToCom[2] = (daysToCom3);
    }
    void setDegree(DegreeProgram iDegree) {
        degree = iDegree;
    }

    string getID() {
        return studentID;
    }
    string getFName() {
        return fName;
    }
    string getLName() {
        return lName;
    }
    string getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    int getDay1() {
        return numDaysToCom[0];
    }
    int getDay2() {
        return numDaysToCom[1];
    }
    int getDay3() {
        return numDaysToCom[2];
    }
    double getAvgDays() {
        double avg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            avg = avg + numDaysToCom[i];
        }
    }
    DegreeProgram getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }
private:
    string studentID;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string email;
    int age;
    int numDaysToCom[3];
    DegreeProgram degree;
};
```

I'm still trying to figure out the multi file system so I am clearly missing something but I just can't seem to wrap my head around exactly what is missing. I tried taking out the degree bit just to see if that was the cause of it which it didn't seem to be. I am early on in the project and simply trying to run the a test to make sure that the student class is getting all the data I feed it and then I was going to ask for an output but haven't been able to make it that far.

Also just hovered over the strings in the constructor and it was considering them constant characters but I couldn't figure out a way to change that to be any different

Comment: Instead of defining a new `class Student {...}` in the cpp file you need to define the methds for the class defined in the header file. `Student::Student(...) { ... }`, `Student::setId(...) { ... }` etc.

Comment: You have two separate, distinct and unrelated `Student` classes.

Comment: So I need to make the changes within the cpp file to make it Student::Student(){}? Would I simply achieve that by moving those functions outside of the actual class {}s?

Comment: is the constructor function Student coming the second one

Comment: See dupes: [C++ Separate header and source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174253/c-separate-header-and-source-file?) and [How to separate a class and its member functions into header and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/how-to-separate-a-class-and-its-member-functions-into-header-and-source-files)

Comment: Yes define the constructor in the cpp file like `Student::Student(){ // Code goes here}` also remove `class Student { // ...};` from the cpp file and do similar to what you did with the constructor to define the rest of the member functions in the cpp file.